# View Visibility Updates Only Occur if singleInstance is Used Over singleTask, Why?

Tags: android, memory-management, view, task, visibility

So I'm making a launcher.

I have the LauncherActivity and inside it there's a inner class which extends PrefWatcher to monitor a SharedPreference change. This PrefWatcher adjusts the layout of LauncherActivity by making views GONE or VISIBLE depending on the preference change.

I recently noticed that the PrefWatcher ALWAYS fires and the code within the PrefWatcher executes without error, though sometimes the visibility of the Views does not change until I back out of the app and re-enter the app. Upon re-entering the app, the Views are displayed correctly based off the SharedPreference which of course has not changed since backing out.

I've found that this behaviour only occurs if I load say 10 or more apps from the launcher. If I start the launcher and load say 3 apps, the behaviour is correct until I go up to around 10, then the Views stop changing visibility again...

Strangely I decided to switch the LauncherActivity from singleTask to singleInstance. While this has worked as a solution, I do not understand WHY this works. To make matters worse, I've noted that various Launchers use singleTask and singleInstance interchangeably.

Could anyone shine some light on this? I'm assuming it has to be memory management...